# Create table view summing all columns in a row and all rows for a column where row name is equal to column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table that looks like this:

```
name      |rock|paper|scissors
__________|____|_____|________
rock      | .5 |  0  |   2
paper     | 2  |  1  |   0
scissors  | 1  |  4  |   2
```

I want to create a postgresql view that sums together the rows and columns per name like so:

```
name      |strong|weak
__________|______|____
rock      |  2.5 | 2.5  
paper     |  3   | 5  
scissors  |  7   | 4
```

What I want in the second table is two columns. One is the sum of all the columns in the row for the first table, separated by name. The second column is the sum of the rows where the column is equal to the name.

---

I can get the `strong` column to work how I want it, but I can't figure out how to get the `weak` column. Here is my most recent attempt.

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    (rock + paper + scissors) AS strong, 
    (sum(rock) + sum(paper) + sum(scissors)) AS weak 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY name;
```

This just produces a table that has the weak column equal to the strong column like so:

```
name      |strong|weak
__________|______|____
rock      |  2.5 | 2.5  
paper     |  3   | 3  
scissors  |  7   | 7
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could possibly be done using a conditional window sum, like :

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    (rock + paper + scissors) AS strong,
    CASE name
        WHEN 'rock'     THEN SUM(rock)     OVER()
        WHEN 'paper'    THEN SUM(paper)    OVER()
        WHEN 'scissors' THEN SUM(scissors) OVER()
    END AS weak
FROM mytable
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=1d736d6fd1424b7d379accbcbdde43ad)**

Comment: There were so many good answers, but I went with this one because it looked the cleanest. I always forget that you can do conditionals in postgres.

Answer (score 2):

The view could be created as shown below:

```
create view v1 as
select
  name,
  rock + paper + scissors as strong,
  (select
     sum(case 
       when t1.name = 'rock' then t2.rock
       when t1.name = 'paper' then t2.paper
       when t1.name = 'scissors' then t2.scissors
       end
     ) from mytable t2
  ) as weak
from mytable t1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select name, (rock + paper + scissors) as strong,
       (case when name = 'rock' then sum(rock) over ()
             when name = 'paper' then sum(paper) over ()
             when name = 'scissors' then sum(scissors) over ()
        end) as weak
from t;
```